# backup database takes login and user backups or not

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2005, backup, sql-server-express

i am using sql server express and visual studio on my office PC.
i have a database **abcDB**. i created a login abclogin with password = 'abcpass' , default database =abcDB ,

now a winform application, is allowed access to abcDB when correct id and password is supplied via textbox.

if i want to use the same application on my home pc, then what tasks would i have to perform :

1. create an .exe of my application
2. install the application from its .exe on my home pc
3. install sql server on my home pc (do i have to install the same version as on my office pc)
4. i would not install sql server management studio, as i only have to use the application and not to play with the database which i do on my office pc)
5. start using the application
6. but what about the database. i would backup it and restore on my home pc. will this also take the backup of the 'abclogin'?  or will i have to create it again from sqlcmd or installing management studio on my home pc .

when i created abclogin default database =abcDB ,then did it store this detail in the abcDB.mdf file or it is stored somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those things like logins are stored in SQL Server master tables - they are **not** part of your backup of `abcDB`.

Users on the other hand are part of your database, so they get backed up together with your data.

So when you restore your database on another computer, your database will contain the users, but if they depend on a login, that login might be missing from that SQL Server's `master` database (and will need to be re-created, e.g. as part of your installation)

Comment: ok sir, so like if i have a software & want to install it on a customer's pc , and the customer would insert data via the software, & in this case i don't want to use windows authentication, so am left with choosing between application roles or sql server login. so i used sql server login. so now, when the customer opens the applcn. then he enters the login. so in this case, i would have to create that login manually from sqlcmd? – sqlchild

Comment: @sqlchild: yes, you would have to create the SQL Server logins **once** at any customer location - typically something you would do during your server-side installation (you are installing a database, on the server, after all - include a script to create the logins and associate your users with those logins)

Comment: but if i chose application roles then? do they come along with the backup with the backup of abcDB?

Comment: @sqlchild: A database role, an application role – these are properties of a database and so are included in your backups. There are also *server roles*. If you have got some specific server roles that take part in your security settings, their setting up should be included in the server installation process (i.e. you set up them just once as well as you do server logins).

Comment: By backup contains the database users - do you mean the full backup or also differential and log backups please?

Comment: Does tlog contain the new database users and permission changes?